# How to extract all date from string using re.search?

Tags: python, regex, date, python-3.6

How to extract all date using `re.search`, when I have multiple dates in the string?

```
date_regex = '\d{1,4}([.\-/])\d{1,2}([.\-/])\d{1,4}'
i = "09/22/2019 - 09/10/2003"
re.search(date_regex, i)
```

It is only returning the first date as:

```
"09/22/2019"
```

but what I want is list of all dates in the string:

```
["09/22/2019", "09/10/2003"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Re.search will only return the first occurance or none you can use findall() here to return more then one.

Comment: Just to note the OP will need to tweak their existing regex though as those unnecessary capture groups are going to through things off

Comment: The downvote is mainly to make this question [eligible for automated deletion](/help/roomba), though perhaps also as a nudge to not answer very common FAQs which are sure to have a duplicate, and to pay attention to spelling and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i = "09/22/2019 - 09/10/2003"
date_regex=r'\b(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20\d\d)\b'
b = re.findall(date_regex, i)
['/'.join(map(str, x)) for x in b ]
```

output

```
['09/22/2019', '09/10/2003']
```